# Genetic algorithm best way to mutate list/gene

Tags: genetic-algorithm, mutation, dplyr

So if I have a list of x integers what is the best way to mutate that list?

A way to do this would be to pick a random integer and change it but I suspect this would cause a problem if 2 or more elements have to change to achieve a better result.

So what would be the best way? Generating a new random list? Change random number of elements? Maybe another way?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, and this may be slightly off-topic, you should take note that some crossover operations may introduce mutations as a side-effect. For instance, suppose that you use binary encoding and that some discrete element E of the solution is encoded with multiple bits, then if the crossover point is in the middle of the binary representation of E, the resulting child will most likely have its E element different that that of both its parents' E elements.

In your case, I would suggest that you mutate a certain percentage of the elements of your list. This percentage does not need to be fixed, and it could possibly be better if it were not (e.g., you could choose to mutate between 1% and 3% of the integers, chosen randomly).

If you use binary encoding, take a look at [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code), which can be interesting if you want your children's mutations to be more "local" (i.e., remain closer to the neighborhoods of their parents).

Answer (score 0):

There is no best/optimal way. All your suggestions seem good. Try each and see which works best.

What's important (and is often neglected) is to define what "better performance" means. Having this measure will help you tune your parameters (e.g. Mutation rate). Typically performance is some form of fitness convergence rate. Good luck!